# NSURLErrorDomain -1100 for iOS File

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation to convert a captured video on iPhone, and I have it exported to the tmp path of my app. I generate the output path dynamically based on the location of the captured video. When I use that outputUrl and make an AVURLAsset out of it, it seems like theres a NSURLErrorDomain -1100 saying path doesn't exist? I've tried to access the duration of the video and it says 0, and making a thumbnail returns that error. I'm using a file explorer and it shows the converted video was exported. Is there an error with making the outputURL, or maybe it's an issue with permissions?

```
NSURL *urlDirectory = [url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSURL *outputUrl = [urlDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"encodedVideo.MP4"];
```

Doing an NSLog shows the output directory as something like this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/<app_id>/tmp/capture-T0x1752ee40.tmp.PdTWVj/encodedVideo.MP4
```

Comment: Are you getting the original video using ALAssetsLibrary?  If so, are you maintaining a strong reference to it in a property or instance variable?  All of the assets you get from the user's library become inaccessible as soon as your ALAssetsLibrary object gets deallocated.  If not, can you expand on what your project does and show some more code leading up to this point?

Comment: The original video is referenced by:
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [weakSelf addVideoToNote:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
        }];

info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] holds the path to the file on the device, and I have this URL passed to two following methods after that, which eventually leads to the code I included earlier.